# Graduate school admission without college degree

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

Can you apply and be admitted to a graduate school without having an undergraduate degree?

Answer (score 0):

I see no particular reason why a graduate committee may not admit someone without an undergraduate degree. But you'd have to have outstanding -- and well documented -- talents for a committee to take a chance on such a candidate.

Answer (score 0):

Why not? Harvard accepted a college dropout (the offer was not conditional on degree completion and the student never finished their degree) into one of its exclusive post-graduate programs.

http://www.thecrimson.com/article/2006/5/22/bushs-personal-aide-to-enroll-at/